# How to Bulk Create content pages across many pages using Tridion

Tags: content-delivery, sdl-tridion

I need to create content  descriptions across many different brands and I would like to do this in bulk/mass.  Is there functionality in Tridion where I can create a content section then individualize the content across many brands. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "create a content section" I'm assuming you mean a specific content field.

You could look at the Core Service, where you have the ability to open pages (pass in an array of pages or folders etc.) and then iterate through Component Presentations to find the ones you're interested in. Check them out, apply the update (See a1, a2) save and check in.

You may also be interested in reading more about the PowerShell Tool Modules (See a3).

If you're on Tridion 9.6 you may also want to read up (and checkout the video) on the RWS blog (see a4).

- a1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069726/updating-components-using-the-core-service-in-sdl-tridion-2011
- a2: [How to update the component particular field node using core service](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11597/how-to-update-the-component-particular-field-node-using-core-service)
- a3: https://github.com/pkjaer/tridion-powershell-modules
- a4: https://community.rws.com/product-groups/tridion/tridion-sites/b/blog-posts/posts/introducing-tridion-sites-rest-api